# Как выводить на экран не более 10 строк таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlet

Есть следующая таблица:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="15"></td>
                    <td><button type="button"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на экран выводилось не более 10 строк, а под таблицей были ссылки на 1,2...n страницу?

Подскажите в каком направлении думать. Спасибо!

Comment: Про ссылки не понял. Из каждого не вместившегося tr делать ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример с 4 tr, максимум tr стоит 2, для двух которые скрываются делаются ссылки исходя от `data-link` атрибута, там храниться массив где первый индекс это сама ссылка, а второй – текст ссылки.

```js
const maxTr = 2
const tr = document.querySelectorAll('#my-table tr')
const links = document.querySelector('#my-table-links')

;[...tr].slice(maxTr).forEach(i => {
  const [link, text] = JSON.parse(i.dataset.link)
  
  i.classList.add('hide')
  
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.className = 'my-link'
  a.textContent = text
  a.href = link
  
  links.append(a)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.my-link {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table" class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center">
  <tr data-link="1">
    <td>Content1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="15"></td>
    <td><button type="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-link="2">
    <td>Content2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="15"></td>
    <td><button type="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-link='["/ваш/путь/", "My content 3 link"]'>
    <td>Content3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="15"></td>
    <td><button type="button"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-link='["/ваш/второй-путь/", "My content 4 link"]'>
    <td>Content4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="15"></td>
    <td><button type="button"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="my-table-links"></div>
```